# EmberJS Table Component

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

Does anyone know any table component that works with EmberJS 2.6?
My requirements are next:

Fixed header
Resizable columns
Sortable by column(s)

I know about [these one](http://opensource.addepar.com/ember-table/#/overview) but it does not work with current EmberJS version and it looks like it wont in near future...I tried two forks that looks decent but no luck, so im looking for replacement. Also I don't mind using some heavy library's I don't need since its for node webkit app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ember Light Table](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-light-table) should work for you.

It has all your requirements, and is fairly easy to customize.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ember-table has branch https://github.com/addepar/ember-table/tree/cyril/ember-2.0 for ember 2.0

But my experience says that better check https://www.emberaddons.com/?query=table cause Addepar not pay enough attention to ember-table. We try ember-tabello - still work fine